# When I tap thumbnails it doesn't change main image in mobile view only but it is working properly in Desktop

Tags: image, onclick, magento-1.9, thumbnails, product

When I tap in catalog page thumbnails (different images of product), It must change accordingly, but **it shows the same image with url suffix "#" at the end and suddenly scroll to up** . **It only happens in mobile**, tablet view and in MAC. It is working fine in Desktop view. The URL of my website is https://mirakin.com/minimalists/erratic.html when I click on thumbnails of any product ,URL changes to https://mirakin.com/minimalists/erratic.html# Please help me to resolve it. I have gone through the flex slider java script. I am using Magento 1.9
You can also visit to the website and open in desktop and mobile phone.

I have also replaced the code.but it doesn't work.

```js
$(window).scroll(function() {
  if ($(document).scrollTop() > 50) {
    $('header').addClass('shrink');
  } else {
    $('header').removeClass('shrink');
  }
});


To

jQuery = jQuery.noConflict();
jQuery(window).scroll(function() {
  if (jQuery(document).scrollTop() > 50) {
    jQuery('header').addClass('shrink');
  } else {
    jQuery('header').removeClass('shrink');
  }
});
```

please let me know if anyone available.

Answer (score 0):

There is an error in your app.js for "Block collapsing (on smaller viewports)" (function starting from line 989):

`this.toggleElements.toggleSingle is not a function`

As far as I can see, this error is the related one.

Besides you maybe wanna check your 404er errors in the console.